# In project 'app' a resolved Google Play services library dependency depends on another at an exact version (e.g. "[16.0

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

- hi i am implementing firebase crash analytics.when i added firebase
  sdk in my project these error showing. i try to solve by degrading
  sdk it show some error.when i run the app above error is keep
  showing. i stuck in this for log time i tried to lowering
  implementation but it shows another error. so can you please solve
  this issue for me.below added the build error and gradle code.so can
  please solve thsis issue.

  Exception is:
  org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugBuild'.
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:38)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
      at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
      at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
      at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
      at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
      at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
      at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
      at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
      at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
      at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:43)
      at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:355)
      at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:343)
      at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:336)
      at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
      at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:134)
      at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
      at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:202)
      at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:193)
      at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
      at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
      at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
      at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
  Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: In project 'app' a resolved Google Play services library dependency depends on another at an exact version (e.g. "[18.0.
  0]", but isn't being resolved to that version. Behavior exhibited by the library will be unknown.

  Dependency failing: com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0 -> com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@[18.0.0], but fire
  base-iid version was 20.1.5.

  The following dependencies are project dependencies that are direct or have transitive dependencies that lead to the art
  ifact with the issue.
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-config@17.0.0
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@18.0.0
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-core@17.0.1
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics@{strictly 17.0.0}
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-config@{strictly 17.0.0}
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics@17.2.2
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@{strictly 20.1.5}
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-core@{strictly 17.0.1}
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@{strictly 18.0.0}
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics@17.0.0
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api@{strictly 17.2.2}
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics@{strictly 17.2.2}

  For extended debugging info execute Gradle from the command line with ./gradlew --info :app:assembleDebug to see the dep
  endency paths to the artifact. This error message came from the google-services Gradle plugin, report issues at https://
  github.com/google/play-services-plugins and disable by adding "googleServices { disableVersionCheck = false }" to your b
  uild.gradle file.

  - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

  BUILD FAILED in 5s

  ```
      buildscript {
          ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.31'
          repositories {
              google()
              jcenter()
              maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
          }
          dependencies {
              classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
              classpath "com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.8.2"
              classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
              classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:2.0'
              classpath 'net.sf.proguard:proguard-gradle:6.0.3'
              classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
              classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
              classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.1.0'

              // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
              // in the individual module build.gradle files
          }
      }

      allprojects {
          repositories {
              google()
              jcenter()
              maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
              maven {
                  url "https://maven.google.com"
                  // Google's Maven repository
              }
          }
      }

      task clean(type: Delete) {
          delete rootProject.buildDir
      }


  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
  apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
  apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
  apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

  android {
      compileSdkVersion 28
      defaultConfig {
          applicationId "com.taxi.deals.newuser"
          minSdkVersion 19
          targetSdkVersion 28
          versionCode 90
          versionName "0.7"
          testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
          vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
          multiDexEnabled true

      }

      /* signingConfigs {
          release {
              storeFile file("")
              storePassword ""
              keyAlias ""
              keyPassword ""
          }
      }*/
      buildTypes {

          debug {

              buildConfigField("String", "BASE_URL", "\"http://1-dot-taxi2.appspot.com\"")
              buildConfigField("String", "BASE_URL_SWISS", "\"http://1-dot-taxi2.appspot.com\"")
              buildConfigField("String", "BASE_URL_IN", "\"http://1-dot-taxi2.appspot.com\"")
              buildConfigField("String", "API_KEY", "\"ABCXYZ123TEST\"")
          }
          release {
              minifyEnabled false
              useProguard false
              proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
              buildConfigField("String", "BASE_URL", "\"http://1-dot-taxi2.appspot.com\"")
              buildConfigField("String", "BASE_URL_SWISS", "\"http://1-dot-taxi2.appspot.com\"")
              buildConfigField("String", "BASE_URL_IN", "\"http://1-dot-taxi2.appspot.com\"")
              buildConfigField("String", "API_KEY", "\"ABCXYZ123TEST\"")
          }
      }
  /*    sourceSets {
          main {
              manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
              java.srcDirs = ['src']
              resources.srcDirs = ['src']
              aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
              renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
              res.srcDirs = ['res']
              assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
          }
          uat {
              res.srcDir('uat/res')
          }
          prod {
              res.srcDir('prod/res')
          }
          // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
          // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
          // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
          // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
          // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
          // by a similar customization.
          debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
          release.setRoot('build-types/release')
      }

      flavorDimensions ""
      productFlavors {
          uat {
              applicationId 'http://1-dot-taxi2deals.appspot.com'
              versionCode 1


          }
          prod {
              applicationId 'http://1-dot-taxi2deal.appspot.com'
              versionCode 1
          }
      }*/
      repositories {
          maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
      }
      buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
      compileOptions {
          targetCompatibility 1.8
          sourceCompatibility 1.8
      }
      lintOptions {
          checkReleaseBuilds false
      }

      bundle {
          language {
              // Specifies that the app bundle should not support
              // configuration APKs for language resources. These
              // resources are instead packaged with each base and
              // dynamic feature APK.
              enableSplit = false
          }
      }
  }

  dependencies {
      implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.+'
      implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
      implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
      implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:28.0.0'
      implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:28.0.0'
      implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
      implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
      implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
      implementation 'com.github.GoodieBag:CarouselPicker:v1.1'

      //Adding Fast Android Networking
      implementation 'com.github.matecode:Snacky:1.0.3'
      implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0"
      //external lib


      implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
      annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
      implementation 'com.romandanylyk:pageindicatorview:1.0.1@aar'
      implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5"

      implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.5'
      implementation 'com.chootdev:typefaced:1.1.7'
      // reactive
      implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.12"
      implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.2'
      /*Dagger*/
      implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.16"
      annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.16"
      compileOnly "org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28"
      implementation 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'
      // network
      implementation "com.amitshekhar.android:rx2-android-networking:1.0.2"
      // swipe view
      implementation "com.mindorks:placeholderview:0.6.1"
      // logger
      implementation "com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.7.0"
      //country num
      implementation 'com.hbb20:ccp:2.2.4'
      //map
      implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'
      implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
     implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.1.0'
      implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:19.0.0'
      implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:17.0.0'
      implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0'
      implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.0.0'
      implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.11.0'
      debugImplementation "com.amitshekhar.android:debug-db:1.0.3"
      testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
      androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
      androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
      implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
      implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
      implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
      implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0'
      implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.0'
      implementation 'com.novoda:merlin:1.2.0'
      implementation project(path: ':Arclibrary')
      implementation project(':trail')
      implementation project(':cartype')

      implementation 'com.yarolegovich:mp:1.0.9'
      implementation('com.paytm:pgplussdk:1.2.3') {
          transitive = true;
      }
      implementation 'com.paytm:pgplussdk:1.2.3'
      implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.8@aar') {
          transitive = true;
      }
      //stripe payment gateway
      implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-android:6.1.2'
      implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
      implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
      implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:1.2.1'
      implementation 'com.github.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.3'
      implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.1'
      implementation "com.squareup.moshi:moshi:1.6.0"
      implementation "com.adyen.checkout:ui:2.4.4"
      implementation "com.adyen.checkout:nfc:2.4.4"
      implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:16.0.0'
      implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.7.2'
      implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[5,6)'
      implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
      implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
      implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:17.0.0'
      implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.1'
      implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.0.0'
  }
  apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
  apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'


  configurations.all {
      resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
  }
  repositories {
      mavenCentral()
  }
  ```

Comment: show error log please.

Comment: Provide a [mcve].

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya   i add the error log now can you check

Comment: @Богдан Опир  i add the error log now can you check

Answer (score 0):

```
 implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.9'
```

The only dependency of crashlytics is working for me

Comment: for latest they using above firebase crash analytics. Yours is used for fabric crash analytics

Answer (score 0):

Firebaser here -

It looks like you're running into an issue of mismatched dependencies, where you've defined the version of IID but there are other dependencies pulling in different versions of that library. There are a few things that I can think of that might help:

1. Upgrading your version of `com.google.gms:google-services` (4.3.3)
2. Upgrading your version of Firebase Messaging (20.1.3)
3. You may also try adding that disableVersionCheck that you mentioned in your post, in case you haven't already.